# Getting 401 (Unauthorized) error with axios post

Tags: reactjs, axios

I made register and login pages with Reactjs. If I use Postman, `POST` request works fine, but if I'm trying to send request with axios I always get `401 (Unauthorized)` error. This is my code to Register:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:1338/users/', {
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
username: this.state.userName,
email: this.state.userEmail,
password: this.state.userPassword,
confirmed: true,
blocked: false

})
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

I checked and `state` variables is actually correct, I even tried hardcoding strings straight into `username`, `email` and `password`. But it throws same error anyways. What could be wrong?

EDIT:

I got suggestion to check **Request Headers** in my browser, When I try registering I get two instances:

[image]

I checked **Request Headers** and I found that there's `Authorization: Bearer null`. But when registering I don't event send Authorization headers. I got suggestion to clear my cookies and localstorage, how exactly can I do it?

Comment: Are you receiving data on the backend? try to console.log them and see.

Comment: First of all, you are sending your headers as part of the JSON payload. If you want to send custom headers, the go into the third parameter of `axios.post`. That may although not be a problem, as axios will set the correct content-type header automatically. Second, have you debugged your server if it correctly interprets the sent data? Are you using the correct authentication scheme?

Comment: And please also share the request generated by postman. If it works there, but not with your JS code, it's quite a chance, that you did something wrong. But nobody can help you because nobody knows, how a working request must look like ... You can click on `</>` on the far right of your request tab in postman and select a language to export your request to. For instance cURL. Please share the result of this export.

Comment: Thanks for answers, the thing is, I was using 12.x.x nodejs, I updated it to 14.x.x . When I was using older version my api was starting fine, register and login was working fine with axios, When I updated Node, my api project for some reason stopped working (Strapi), but I made new Strapi project, made same tables there and added same user permissions. Now I'm always getting this 401 error. I can also put cURL from postman here, should I pot it in answer? But I'm pretty positive it's not the case, because it was working before.

Comment: In addition I just checked directly link like `http://localhost:1338/users` and it's showing fine, not `Forbidden`

Comment: @derpirscher I realised that in Postman if Authentication is provided while I want to register new user, I get 401 error, could it be that somehow React sends jwt token and I get that error? But I didn't provide headers for `authorization`, that shouldn't be the case

Comment: Check what is sent to the server in the developer tools of the browser. No axios does not randomly create jwt tokens and add them to requests, unless you speficially tell it to do so. When you say you recreated the server component, check if you recreated the data correctly.  Check what the requesthandler at the server does with this data. Check if the data sent from the client fits the data stored on the server. Given the code above nobody can help you, because nobody knows, whats really sent to the server and nobody knows what the server does with the received data ...

Comment: To be exact I get this `{"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Invalid token."}` error. But as you can see in the code I don't send `Authorization` header, I'm actually lost, doesn't even know what to do anymore, I will try recreating server component again I guess or something like that, maybe I'll figure something out